# how can I convert this code (theano) to a simple python lign

Tags: python, theano

how can I convert this code (theano) to a simple python lign

```
[h_vals, _, y_vals] = theano.scan(fn=lstm_Step,
                              sequences=[dict(input=inputs, taps=[0])],
                              outputs_info=[h0, c0, None],
                              non_sequences=[Whx, Whh, Wcx, Wch, Wyh, bh, bc, by],
                              strict=True)[0]
```

Comment: What is 'lign'? You mean 'line'?

Comment: yes , I means python code.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'one line'?

Comment: I'd like to convert this theano code to a simple python code

Comment: knowing that I have this function at first:    def lstm_Step(x_t, h_tm1, c_tm1, Whx, Whh, Wcx, Wch, Wyh, bh, bc, by):
    # preact = x_t + h_tm1 # tensor.dot(h_, tpars[_p(prefix, 'U')]) orthogonalized h
    preact = Whx.dot(x_t) + Whh.dot(h_tm1) + bh
    g = T.nnet.sigmoid(preact)
    i, o, f = g[:n_h_dim], g[n_h_dim:2*n_h_dim], g[2*n_h_dim:]
    c_in = T.tanh(Wcx.dot(x_t) + Wch.dot(h_tm1) + bc)
    c = f * c_tm1 + i * c_in
    h = o * T.tanh(c)
    y = Wyh.dot(h) + by # regression
    # RNN classification output y = T.nnet.softmax(Wyh.dot(h) + by)[0]
    return [h, c, y]

Comment: This is already a pythond code. You're using a python library `theano`. If need to avoid using `theano`, then you need to implement in python what this library does, but I don't think it's a good option.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example of what I means,

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt


def add_multiply(a, b, k):
return a + b + k, a * b * k


def python_main():
x = 1
y = 2
k = 1
tuples = []
for i in range(5):
    x, y = add_multiply(x, y, k)
    tuples.append((x, y, k))
return tuples


def theano_main():
x = tt.constant(1, dtype='uint32')
y = tt.constant(2, dtype='uint32')
k = tt.scalar(dtype='uint32')
outputs, _ = theano.scan(add_multiply, outputs_info=[x, y],    non_sequences=[k], n_steps=5)
g = theano.grad(tt.sum(outputs), k)
f = theano.function(inputs=[k], outputs=outputs + [g])
tuples = []
xvs, yvs, _ = f(1)
for xv, yv in zip(xvs, yvs):
    tuples.append((xv, yv, 1))
return tuples


print 'Python:', python_main()
print 'Theano:', theano_main()
```

So as you say @Nurzhan I need to know what this library does especially what's the means of theano.scan.